# Repeat the higher numbers (>1) on column ($AE$3:$AE) depends how many the duplicate names are in on column ($R$3:$R)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I want to copy the values but just only the higher than one (>1) **from column $AE$3:$AE** which is I'd given the name with "**MANUAL
INPUT OF NUMB**" and want to set those values **onto a column $AG$3:$AG** then repeat them **depends on how many the duplicate names are in a column $R$3:$R** which is I'd given the column the name with "**N A M E**". Can we make this happend with formula or arrayformula ? or Chould we do this by any others way as an alternative ways if the formula doesn't work or can't do this doing such a like this thing or custom formulas something like that ?

And I've tried with my tests formulas :
`=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT("‍"&FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF($AE$3:$AE>1;$AE$3:$AE&"​";""));"";""));$AE$3:$AE);"‍"));"​");"where Col1 is not null";1))`
after doing some **research on column $AG$3:$AG** and it's failed it doesn't work at all as I want it as I imagine it. Please see my pictures that I've attached down below these and see also the table I've created for more further explanation.

|  | > R < | > AE | AF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 | **N A M E** | **MANUAL INPUT OF NUMB** | **EXPECT OUTPUT** |
| 3 |  |  |  |
| 4 | AAA |  |  |
| 5 | AAA |  |  |
| 6 | AAA |  |  |
| 7 | AAA |  |  |
| 8 | AAA |  |  |
| 9 | BBB | 3 | 3 |
| 10 | BBB |  | 3 |
| 11 | BBB |  | 3 |
| 12 | CCC | 2 | 2 |
| 13 | CCC |  | 2 |
| 14 | BBB | 2 | 2 |
| 15 | BBB |  | 2 |
| 16 | BBB |  | 2 |
| 17 | CCC |  |  |
| 18 | CCC |  |  |
| 19 | BBB | 1 |  |
| 15 | BBB |  |  |

[image: Example Picture]

[image: another tries from me & player0 and make it clearly about output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(c; IF(c>1; c; ))(IF(A2:A="";; 
 VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A); IF(B2:B<>""; {ROW(A2:A)\ B2:B}); 2))))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(z, y, IF(y, z, ))(LAMBDA(x, IF(x>1,x,))(IF(A3:A="",,VLOOKUP(ROW(R3:R),IF(B3:B<>"",{ROW(R3:R),B3:B}),2))), ""<>IF(VLOOKUP(ROW(R3:R),IF(IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROWS(A:A)-1)<>A3:A, row(A3:A), )<>"",{ROW(R3:R),IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROWS(A:A)-1)<>A3:A, row(A3:A), )}),2)=IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(R3:R),IF((IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROWS(A:A)-1)<>A3:A, row(A3:A), )<>"")*(B3:B>1),{ROW(R3:R),IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROWS(A:A)-1)<>A3:A, row(A3:A), )}),2)), VLOOKUP(ROW(R3:R),IF(IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROWS(A:A)-1)<>A3:A, row(A3:A), )<>"",{ROW(R3:R),IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROWS(A:A)-1)<>A3:A, row(A3:A), )}),2), )))
```

[image]

Comment: but it seems not wok for gsheet mobile because I often open and check my gsheets data on mobile rather than on desktop or laptop. The #ERROR! has coming as display value when I input it your formula and little bit given a modify to adapting into my case `=INDEX(LAMBDA($AH$3:$AH;IF($AH$3:$AH>1;$AH$3:$AH;))(IF($R$3:$R="";;VLOOKUP(ROW($R$3:$R);IF($AE$3:$AE<>"";{ROW($R$3:$R)\$AE$3:$AE});2))))` and the warning note has came out too as a clue it says "**Formula parse error.**"

Comment: @DebyFerdian you used it incorrectly. use in AH3: `=INDEX(LAMBDA(x; IF(x>1;x;))(IF(R3:R="";;VLOOKUP(ROW(R3:R);IF(AE3:AE<>"";{ROW(R3:R)\AE3:AE});2))))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziWZi.png

Comment: Ups .. Sorry my apologies it's my bad @player0. But still it's kinda a lack of effectively function when **the number of somes are blank** from the middle then the output cames out with a given the repeat numbers was an the above them. How do we'll fix this ?  [Please see my another pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpDQf.png) I'd updated and the table an above to make them clearly to understand!

Comment: @DebyFerdian let me confirm something... do you need column AE to act as manual input in the first place? asking because we could just put a condition directly in the formula so you wouldn't need manually input anything. it would run automatically

Comment: Yeah .. I know @player0 but what I mean is that the AE3:AE column is the data was collecting based on the **date paid** and the **AE3:AE column was act as a column helper** to get their version whos was users and which one the group that **users are getting paid**!

Comment: you are really absolutely wonderful sucha nice and good person. Thank you so much player0 I'm so happy well you are finally the saver of my time! Thanks a lot three thousands for you once again player0  q^_^p